# iPhone twitter integration: NSXMLParserDelegate protocol not found error

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsxmlparser, twitter-oauth

Im very new to iPhone programming, and am facing this really weird issue with importing the Twitter+OAuth libraries for implementing some basic twitter integration into my program.

My SDK is iPhone 3.1.3. After i drag-drop the twitter+oauth library, i add the header path and the library search path 
[$(SDKROOT)\usr...whatever as i found in [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/) tutorial ]

I then added the libxml2.dylib framework to the project. When i compile the project, i get six errors, all the same from different .h files that say
"NSXMLParserDelegate protocol not found".

Please help! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of NSXMLParserDelegate

> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

It simply wont work if you are using SDK 3.1.3

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081595/nsxmlparserdelegate-and-iphone-sdk-3-1-x) question for further info

Comment: Thanks... Could you point out me as to what i should do for twitter integration now?